# How do I keep the line breaks intact, when appending a div with posted html?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: step 1 2 3]

Below and above are the 3 steps of what happens.

```
var newcontent = $("#commenthere").val();
alert(newcontent)
$('#commentarea').replaceWith(newcontent);
```

What I want is when the content is appended/replaced, whatever, that it displays

> 1
>
> 2

on the page instead of `1 2`

I tried replacing `\n` with `<br>` using `replace`, but it doesn't work as it causes syntax errors as it moves the javascript code to a new line, breaking the function.

Comment: How did you try? Post the code. (Also, `str_replace` sounds like a PHP function. JavaScript has a String method simply called `replace`.)

Comment: Btw, you have a syntax error in your code above. `$('#commentarea)` should be `$('#commentarea')`.

Comment: I've fixed the syntax error, and I updated to the proper version of the function called `replace`, which I did use.

Answer (score 3):

Setting the div's style
 `white-space: pre` should fix this.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
str = str.replace( '\n', '<br>' );
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/QvFdy/1/

Comment: I'm getting this result. http://imageshack.us/a/img854/5977/causingalinebreak.png

Comment: @desbest JavaScript source code is static. When you write `'\n'`, it will stay that way. Unless you use some kind of compiler on your original source code. Do you do that?

Comment: You're right. It must be Ramaze. I'm using a ruby framework which is compiling my .xhtml files, which is why I'm allowed to use `<!doctype html>` in them without having a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a `<pre />` tag, that will format the text including all white space as it comes.